# Почему во встроенных документах не работает аргумент unique?

Tags: python, mongodb, nosql, mongoengine

Я использую Mongoengine для Mongodb версии 4.x и у меня возникла следующая проблема:
Я использую примерно такую структуру документа

```
class Owner(Document):
    clusters = EmbeddedDocumentListField(ClusterOwner)

    meta = {
        'indexes': [...]
    }

class ClusterOwner(EmbeddedDocument):
    _id = ObjectIdField(default=lambda: ObjectId(), primary_key=True, unique=True, required=True)
    name = StringField(min_length=3, max_length=9, unique=True, required=True)
```

Однако два кластера с одинаковым name создаются без проблем. Почему?

[Здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12403992/how-to-create-an-index-in-mongoengine-to-be-unique-true-and-sparse-true) указано, что стоит прописать это всё в meta - но зачем, если есть аргументы и почему они не работают?